# lambda calculus, expanded and compressed form have different beta-reductions?

Tags: lambda-calculus

given

```
S=\x.\y.\z.x z (y z)
```

and

```
K=\x.\y.x
```

I cannot understand how two beta equivalent forms of the same expression (S K K) yield different results in untyped lambda calculus if I start from the (S K K) form or the equivalent expanded form:

```
(S K K) = ((S K) K) -> ((\y.(\z.((K z) (y z)))) K) -> (\z.((K z) (K z))) ->
(\z.((\y.z) (K z))) -> (\z.z) -> 4 reductions!

(S K K) = \x.\y.\z.x z (y z) \x.\y.x \x.\y.x -> 0 reductions!
```

It seems the compressed and the expanded form have different parenthesizations, indeed the first one is parenthsized as:

```
(S K K) = ((S K) K)
```

while the second as:

```
\x.\y.\z.x z (y z) \x.\y.x \x.\y.x =
(\x.(\y.(\z.(((x z) (y z)) (\x.(\y.(x (\x.(\y.x)))))))))
```

Does anyone have any insight into this???
Thank you

Comment: You should probably ask this on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [formal definition of lambda calculus on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Formal_definition). An abstraction and an application always have a set of enclosing parentheses.
This means more correct definitions of S and K are:

```
S = (\x.\y.\z.x z (y z))
```

and

```
K = (\x.\y.x)
```

Substituting these in `(S K K)` gives the correct result.

Comment: That was illuminating.. thank you..

Answer (score 1):

In `(S K K)`, some parentheses are implicit. This form is an abbreviation for `((S K) K)` since function application is always binary and is considered left-associative.

Comment: but if I have to execute (S K K) and decide to transform it in its expanded form (S K K) = \x.\y.\z.x z (y z) \x.\y.x \x.\y.x and parenthesize it from this expanded form, shouldn't I get the same result? After all they are two equivalent representations of the same formula!

Comment: @dendini: if you evaluate `(S K K)`, you must first insert the missing parentheses, if not on paper/screen then at least in your head.

Comment: So you're saying that S is equivalent to \x.\y.\z.x z (y z), K is equivalent to \x.\y.x however (K S S) is not equivalent to \x.\y.\z.x z (y z) \x.\y.x \x.\y.x because (K S S) is equivalent to ((K S) S) which is not equivalent to \x.\y.\z.x z (y z) \x.\y.x \x.\y.x ??? I am still a little puzzled..

Comment: @dendini: there are implicit parentheses in lambda calculus notation. This should be in your textbook, in a notation section or similar.